# rdlc not printing properly after deployment in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, rdlc

I created a windows form application that is intended for windows 7 use. the program is running perfectly while in development. including the rdlc report viewer. and I developed the application on my computer that has windows 10 installed OS on it.

but when I publish my applications and installed them on the client PC which has windows 7 installed OS. all functioning well except for the printing of ID. it prints but does not print correctly based on the expected output. I also tried to transfer my unpublished application to the client's PC, but the same problem occurs when printing. while it all works on my computer.

what solution shall I do? and what causes the problem?

thanks in advance. BTW I'm using VS 2013 ultimate.

[image printed on clients PC (widows 7)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkRQi.jpg)

It should look like this.

[printed on my PC (windows 10)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZcEc.jpg)

Comment: What does "not print correctly" mean? What is the id on the image you've linked?  Are you able to show us what it should look like?

Comment: I mean it prints, but it does not print correctly. the images and the fonts are printed in bigger size. just like zoomed in.

Comment: Are you using any specific fonts? And if so, are they available on your target machine?  Is the target machine using the same code pages, regional settings etc as you development machine?

Comment: I just used arial font. What do you mean code pages?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_code_page

Comment: how can I check my code page?. sorry, I'm not familiar with those settings. I'm just a beginner.

Comment: I think my project used the default utf-8 encoding, I saw it on the app.manifest file.    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>